# Change the system date and time android programmatically

Tags: android, calendar

I am trying to set the calendar for my application using :

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(2010, 1, 1, 12, 00, 00);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setTime(c.getTimeInMillis());
```

permission:

```
android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE
```

getting exception:
**Neither user 10215 nor current process has android.permission.SET_TIME.**

Comment: Its very clear from the error message that you app doesn't have permission to set time.

Comment: have you solved this? anyways, I think you need to require superuser access.

Answer (score 0):

It's very clear from your error message that your app doesn't have permission to change the system time.

Use this permission in the `manifest.xml`

```
 <permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME"
    android:protectionLevel="signature|system"/>
```

See the [documentation here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SET_TIME)

Comment: Not for use by third-party applications.

Answer (score 0):

add this in your manifest

```
  <permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME"
               android:protectionLevel="signature|system"
    />
```

Comment: Not for use by third-party applications.